# Overlap in the incoming and outgoing Deep Space Station’s (DSS's) uplink/downlink windows

Tags: deep-space-network

I want to create an antenna array of DSS-25 of Goldstone Deep space Communication Complex (DSCC) and DSS-35 of Canberra complex to communicate with Mars Reconnoissance Orbiter (MRO). Suppose that DSS-25 of Goldstone DSCC is currently communicating with the MRO and DSS-35 of Canberra DSCC has next communication pass scheduled with the MRO.

On average, what is the duration of the overlap in the incoming (Canberra) and outgoing (Goldstone) station's communication windows during which they could be used as antenna array?

Comment: The DSN does not support arraying antennas at two different complexes.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks. Do you think they will support antenna arraying at two different complexes in future? Can you suggest me any documents where they have information about overlap of incoming and outgoing station's communication windows?

Comment: I doubt it. There's not much value. You can compute the overlap yourself from the locations of the complexes and that we generally don't operate the antennas below 10° from the horizon.

Comment: @MarkAdler I don't understand (yet) the thing discussed in [Two DSN stations used in VLBI measurement; how a third station serves as a “relay” to tie-together observations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32333/12102)  but might it work by at least temporarily "arraying" the third station somehow?